Detect iOS "darkwake" state in a flutter app
I have a server synchronization task set up using Timer.periodic(..) using dart/flutter, but I've noticed that my macOS Sequoia goes sporadically into a "darkwake" mode during sleep and then the sync task is beeing executed. Here are some relevant log entries:
2024-11-25 21:22:38 +0100 Assertions              PID 520(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 20 seconds to query model for inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000856f [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-11-25 21:22:38 +0100 Assertions              PID 520(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 20 seconds to query model for inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000856f [System: PrevIdle]
2024-11-25 21:22:38 +0100 Assertions              PID 630(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008570 [System: PrevIdle]

In this "darkwake" state, I want to prevent the synchronization task from executing to save battery, especially since it often fails due to the system going back to sleep before completion or due to lack of internet connectivity.
Do you have any suggestions on how to detect this "darkwake" state and prevent the sync task from running?
Thanks!

I dont know how but maybe with MethodChannel or flutter_local_notifications and listen IORegisterForSystemPower?
